# order list where top level order is unknown

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

To order a list with Linq we have to call `OrderBy` first en call `ThenBy` on the result for subordinate orderings.

I'm in a situation now where I do not know the top level ordering before hand. I have a list of of orderings which should be applied conditionally.

Like this:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<int, string, DateTime>>();
list.Add(new Tuple<int, string, DateTime>(1, "B", new DateTime(2020, 1, 1)));
list.Add(new Tuple<int, string, DateTime>(2, "A", new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)));
list.Add(new Tuple<int, string, DateTime>(3, "C", new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)));

var orderedList = list;

if (sortByString)
{
    orderdedList = orderedList.ThenBy(listItem => listItem.Item2);
}

if (sortByDateTime)
{
    orderedList = orderedList.ThenBy(listItem => listItem.Item3);
}

orderList = orderedList.ThenBy(listItem => listItem.Item1);
```

So the list will always be ordered by Item1, and conditionally by Item2 and/or Item3 first.

How to accomplish this in C#? Solutions without Linq are also welcome.

Comment: what's wrong with what you have - just write `var orderedList = list.OrderBy(t => t.Item1);` and keep everything **but** the last line

Comment: `ThenBy` is only available on `IOrderedEnumerable`, so you could use a type check. If `IOrderedEnumerable` use `ThenBy` else `OrderBy`

Comment: @Carsten The problem with that is that Johan wants the `Item1` ordering *last*. It's not exactly easy to read, but that's what he's written :)

Comment: @Luaan yes sorry - You&Tim already got a solution for this ... I had some issues parsing "So the list will always be ordered by Item1, and conditionally by Item2 and/or Item3 first." exactly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use

```
var orderedItems = list.OrderBy(_ => 1);
```

This gives you the default (non-)ordering, and allows you to add as many other orderings as you want afterwards using just `ThenBy`.

**EDIT:**

As Tim noted, this does carry  a performance penalty - it seems that the default LINQ-to-Objects provider isn't smart enough to rebuild the ordering to get rid of the "non-ordering". This is not a problem if your list is small, but if it's taking non-negligible amount of time, you probably want to do this the hard way.

For example, you could use a helper method like

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AppendOrdering<T, U>(this IEnumerable<T> @this, 
                                                  Func<T, U> selector)
{
  if (@this is IOrderedEnumerable<T>) return @this.ThenBy(selector);

  return @this.OrderBy(selector);
}
```

This isn't *exactly* the same you're doing, but unless you're working on an enumerable that has been ordered before, it's going to work the same way.

Comment: Technically this is _not_ a non-ordering but an ordering by the same constant value. Since that is the same for every item the first `ThenBy` is used and so on.  Probably micro-optimizing but on large collections it can make a difference. Why using a pseudo-comparison if you can start with the right? Example: http://csharppad.com/gist/6d19c47c672c81dc2c52 (30 and 17 seconds on my pc)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Interesting, the difference is much bigger than I expected (in SQL this is a no-op, of course). On my computer, I'm getting 16s vs 12s - still quite expensive if you need to work with long lists, but not quite as terrifying as your 100% increase in runtime. But maybe I just have a bigger CPU cache than you do. I'd definitely go with your solution instead (well, after actually making it work the way the OP wants :D). It's just one of those weird design decisions - I kind of understand the why, but it makes query composition a bit harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

Use an `IOrderedEnumerable` instead of a list and an `if ... else`:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<Tuple<int, string, DateTime>> orderedItems = null;

if (sortByDateTime)
    orderedItems = list.OrderBy(listItem => listItem.Item3);
else if (sortByString)
    orderedItems = list.OrderBy(listItem => listItem.Item2);

orderedItems = orderedItems.ThenBy(listItem => listItem.Item1);
list = orderedItems.ToList();
```

Comment: Note that my sorting conditions were not an `if { } else if { }` but `if { } if { }`. If `sortByString` and `sortByDateTime` are true then the second orderby would overwrite the first.

Comment: @JohanvanderSlikke: ok, wasn't clear. Edited my answer. But if `sortByDateTime` has priority you should use `if(sortByDateTime){}else if(sortByString){}`

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a state machine like the code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        enum State
        {
            One,
            Two,
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            State state = State.A;

            switch (state)
            {
                case State.One:
                    //Order by item one
                    state = State.Two;
                    break;
                case State.Two:
                    //Order by item two or three
                    state = State.One;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}


​
```